# principal ideals, integral domains, ideals,?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

I am stuck trying to grasp this concept. I know that

1. $\Bbb{Z}$ is a PID,
2. $R=\Bbb{Z}[X]$ is not a PID,
3. $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID.

If someone could help me grasp these concepts it would be helpful. Ideally I would like an example of each please?

This is my thinking:

1. If you have $\Bbb{Z}_6$, this is not a PID because it isnt a ID as $2*3=3*2$? But $\Bbb{Z}_7$ is a PID as it is a ID.
2. I am struggling to grasp this one espically, e.g. $\Bbb{Z}[5]$ or $\Bbb{Z}[3]$.
3. As there isn't any unique decomposition meaning like $2*3=3*2$ every $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID? But then I don't understand why $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not a PID?

Is my thinking correct?  Because I am getting mixed up.

Thanks!

Comment: **but $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is a PID as it is a ID** is False... a ring would not be a principal ideal domain just because it is integral domain..

Comment: Ahhh, how do you prove something is a PID? and is not? I thou because PID } is a subset of ID therfore it had to be?

Comment: What is the definition of PID? Surely the answer is in there.

Comment: My point is  **$\mathbb{Z}_7$ is PID not just because it is an integral domain**.. Of course it is a PID... you need to show that any arbitrary ideal is principal...

Comment: I think I am getting confused with the definition?  Am not to sure how to show every ideal is principal? I know the definition I=(a)=ar, r E R, but not to sure how to apply it?

Comment: What do you mean by "Z[5]"? Adjoining 5 to $\Bbb Z$ doesn't do anything... do you mean $\Bbb Z/(5)$? Or something else?

Comment: In general proving something is a PID is not THAT simple but for the rings you will need to prove result for it should be fairly simple.

For instance $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ is a field if $p$ is a prime and ofcourse any field is a PID as they only have two ideals in total.

Comment: I had a question: 'define the concept of a principal ideal. Is Z [sqrt5] a PID" the solution says Z [sqrt5] is not a PID

Comment: I advise you to write down *all* ideals of $\Bbb{Z}_6$ and $\Bbb{Z}_7$. Then you will see which is a principal ideal domain, and which one is not.

Comment: Because the ideal generated by 2 and sqrt5 is noy generated by one element? So am getting confused

Comment: Exactly that Raj... Well you will have to prove it but it should not be very hard.

Comment: Yeah, but am not to sure how to, I have spent a while tying to do it? The only thing I thought of, is as its a polynomial ring you have (2, sqrt5) then you could state its nots a PID as its not generated by omr element?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I will just write up the answer as to why $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is not a PID.

Clearly it suffices to find an ideal which is not principal, ie an ideal which can't possibly be generated by one element. As your guess ($2, \sqrt{5}$) works but you can't just state it, you actually have to prove it.

Suppose it can be generated by element $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$. Then $2 = \alpha \times \beta$ and $\sqrt{5} = \alpha \times \gamma$ for some $\beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$. Can you prove such $\alpha$ can not exist?

Comment: Well and I clearly had to say non unit element $\alpha$

Comment: Would it be going along the process of saying n (x) n(y)= the square ( norm) then following on?

Comment: There should be many different ways but that would be one way for it.